# entrypoint.sh exec: @: not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I was following this tutorial:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

I want to create a Ruby On Rails API with PostgreSQL Database (Dockerized)

But when I run

`docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --api --database=postgresql`

I got this:

`Creating soft-vape-db ... done
/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 8: exec: @: not found`

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: soft-vape-db
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    container_name: soft-vape-api
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I would just run `rails new` locally, and try to make your application work before you bring Docker into it at all.  Package it in Docker as a _last_ step, not a first step.

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes. Use `exec $@`.

Comment: eh? How could your error state "error ... line 8" when your file have 4 lines? Are you sure the error is still relevant to the code you show here?

Comment: I just deleted the comments of the file ;) But it was for this line.

Comment: I still have the error @kichik without the quotes :s 
/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 8: exec: @: not found

Comment: I'm having the same error - this may depend on your OS.  On my mac the error is /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 8: rails: not found.  I know this means the ruby container we've pulled doesn't have gems on it yet.  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old but I also had this problem when using the example from docs so I hope this helps someone. The solution is pretty simple.
The rails new command should be prepended with  `bundle exec`.

So run `docker-compose run web bundle exec rails new . --force --no-deps --api --database=postgresql`