# Rails in docker error when try to start server in Windows WSL2 Docker Desktop Engine(docker compose), but working correctly in a Debian system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, docker, docker-compose

This error message appears to 3 images in composed docker container.

`exec /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`

All images related to Ruby execution of services
Sidekiq, Webpack runned by Ruby executable and Web(rails) services
I have tried change every execution to run loading de Gemfile environment using bundle exec, but nothing worked.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -y curl build-essential libpq-dev postgresql \
 nodejs postgresql-client &&\
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
  curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN gem install bundler:2.3.22
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN gem install foreman
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["bash"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5423:5432
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *****
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'
    depends_on:
      - db
  webpack:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'rm -rf public/packs/* || true && bin/webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3035 -w'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3035:3035"
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - webpack
      - chrome
    env_file: .env_docker
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 5
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file: .env_docker
    environment:
      RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 5
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - webpack
      - sidekiq
volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

Equal to [entrypoint.sh exec: @: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150154/entrypoint-sh-exec-not-found) but not resolved

I really want to change my Debian development OS to Windows and work only with containers, *not looking to Linux or WSL alternatives*

Comment: Since you're working on Windows the issue might be related to line endings in the Dockerfile (Windows' uses `\r\n` while Linux uses `\n`)

Comment: So i have to write a new Dockerfile when build on Windows?
Thanks for the comment @konstantino-strukov, i'm testing it later